# Trying to set factor levels for specific variables in data frame--Lapply returns NA

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

I have survey data, and I am trying to convert multiple variables with categorical data ("Strongly Agree", "Agree" etc) into numbers ("6", "5"..), to analyse them later (with summarise/mean)

I've tried this:

```
df<-read_xlsx("Microdata_1.xlsx")
df[46:59] <- lapply(df[46:59], function(x) factor(x))   

df[46:59] <- lapply(df[46:59], factor, levels=c(6,1,4,3,5,2))

df[46:59] <- lapply(df[46:59], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

but it returns a matrix of NAs

```
prob33 prob34 prob35 prob36 prob37 prob38 prob39 prob40 prob41 prob42 prob43 prob44 prob45 prob46
   <fct>  <fct>  <fct>  <fct>  <fct>  <fct>  <fct>  <fct>  <fct>  <fct>  <fct>  <fct>  <fct>  <fct> 
 1 NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA    
 2 NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA    
 3 NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA    
 4 NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA    
 5 NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA    
 6 NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA    
 7 NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA    
 8 NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA    
 9 NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA    
10 NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
```

Comment: Can you edit your post adding the output of a `dput(head(df))`? Not sure how to interpret the mean of categorical variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What should be set, the numbers, is both the factor *levels* and their *labels*.

In the example below I assume that the categorical data values ("Strongly Agree", "Agree" etc) are known and are in a vector `levs`. The code first coerces the strings to factor, then to numeric.

```
df[2:4] <- lapply(df[2:4], factor, levels = levs, labels = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
df[2:4] <- lapply(df[2:4], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))

str(df)
#'data.frame':  10 obs. of  5 variables:
# $ X: num  -1.207 0.277 1.084 -2.346 0.429 ...
# $ A: num  4 4 5 4 3 4 5 2 5 2
# $ B: num  3 4 4 3 1 3 4 2 3 2
# $ C: num  5 1 3 1 5 1 1 2 1 3
# $ Y: num  0.09 0.5192 0.3843 0.0701 0.3206 ...
```

**Data creation code.**

```
levs <- scan(what = character(),
          text = "
'Strongly disagree'
'Disagree'
'Neither agree nor disagree'
'Agree'
'Strongly agree'
")

set.seed(1234)

n <- 10
df <- data.frame(X = rnorm(n),
                 A = sample(levs, n, TRUE),
                 B = sample(levs, n, TRUE),
                 C = sample(levs, n, TRUE),
                 Y = runif(n),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```